# Blur only text inside input, not whole <input> element

Tags: html, css

For various reasons I want to *graphically* blur (i.e. not focus/blur) the text inside an input of `type=text`, not the whole element.

Is there a way to do this?

I currently have this:

```css
.validation:not(:focus) {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    border:0;
}
    
.validation-border{
    border: 1px black solid;
    z-index:20;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <label>Text</label>
    <span class="validation-border">
        <input class="validation" type="text" value="blurred text"/>
    </span>

    <label>Some text</label>
    <input/>
</p>
```

The last class style definition is to replace the border of the input with of class `validation`.

But this is far from perfect:

1. The border 'perimeter' is not the same dimension
2. If I increase the size of the outer border, I still get some blur leakage

[image: example of mega border and blur leakage]

Is there a better way of blurring the text only, and not the bounding box? Or some other way to cover up the side effects of blurring the input element

Comment: `<input class="validation" type="Text"></input>` isn't valid, it should be `<input class="validation" type="Text" />`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than effecting the whole box, just we change the font color to transparent and add a text shadow effect.

```css
.blur-on-lose-focus:not(:focus) {
     color: transparent;
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" class="blur-on-lose-focus" value="blurred text"/>
</div>
```

This is detailed [here](https://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/).

Comment: I don't know, you tell me. What is tb1, and how do I use it with HTML?

Comment: tb1 is just an css selecter class, you can add following code to your validation class color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

Comment: That still cuts a line out of the bottom of the input box. Also the 'blur effect' is not as good.

Comment: you can also see another effect of blur text here http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/zvgCs/

Comment: This actually turns out to work much better than the other answers, but I couldn't tell because of how the answer was written. I've edited it for clarity, let me know if this is OK, so I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: This is Ok @Pureferret

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot blur the interior of an element (at the time of writing) without also blurring its bounding box, border, etc. An alternative approach would be:

```
<div class="input-like">
  <input>
</div>
```

Where you style the `.input-like` container to look like an input (border, etc.). Then remove the border and other styles from the contained `input` element. At that point you can apply the blur filter to the input and leave the containing element unchanged.

The blur leakage seems to be coming from the white background of the input—try setting `background-color: transparent;` on the input and `background-color: white;` on the containing element.

[Live example.](http://codepen.io/mjswensen/pen/wBQedK)

Comment: This is what I've done in my question, but there are issues with it. See my question for those issues. For a start I don't know how to 'perfectly' imitate the border of an input element? I haven't managed it.

Comment: Ah I see. The blur leakage seems to be coming from the white background of the `input`--have you tried `background-color: transparent;` on the input and `background-color: white;` on the containing element?

Comment: That seems to work a charm. I've also added some padding to the dive so it looks a little more like the other input.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and added a link to the CodePen in my answer.

Comment: Saw and implemented your suggested edit as well, @Pureferret. Thanks.

Comment: to mimick a textbox border, try using the `appearance: textfield` property. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Comment: @Luizgrs thats good but I can't workout how to tweek that so a border appear in the same place without focus

Comment: It may also be worth noting the `appearance` doesn't appear in any CSS spec (to date) and [doesn't have great browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance).